# Match id in array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array let's say arr[] and it has value like

```
0:"r1"
1:"<div><input type='checkbox' id = 'e.r1' value='qw'/>qw<br></div>"
2:"<br/>"
3:"r2"
4:"<input type="text" id="e.r2" size="30" maxlength="32" value="">"
5:"<br/>"
6:"r3"
7:"<input type="text" id="e.r3" size="30" maxlength="32" value="">"
8:"<br/>"
```

I have a dynamic content id which I need to find from array if its exist or not,
So what I did is ,

```
var removedTagIndex =1;
var dynVal = "<div><input type='checkbox' id = 'e.r1' value='qw'/>qw<br></div>"
arr.some(function(item, index) { if($(item.replace(/[:/]/g, '')).attr('id') == $(dynVal).attr('id');) { removedTagIndex = index; return true; } });
```

but I'm getting arr[0] as an index while its on 1st index. how can I find proper index where id exist in array for both condition
1> dynVal's id is: "e.r1" and
2> dynVal's id is: "e.r2".. tell me if you don't get it.. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

If i am correct, you want to know if dynVal exist on the array given above?

```
arr.indexOf(dynVal)
```

This will return the index of the found string.
To answer your question.

```
arr.indexOf(dynVal) > -1 ? true : false;
```

This will return true if dynVal exist on the arr.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I can't do this.. if arr[0] has value res1 and arr[3] has res123 then I won't get proper index in this